# Uploading multiple image with different input file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, file-upload

So I have four input files in my forms and I send it on my global $_FILES with the following indices: front,rear,right and left.

I want to upload these using codeigniter image class library. This is my code:

```
public function upload_to_temp($id, $folder, $tags){
            $path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public/resources/temps/' . $folder );
            //makes a directory
            mkdir($path . '/' . $id, 0700);
            //navigate to the newly created path
            $path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public/resources/temps/' . $folder . '/' . $id);

            if(isset($tags)){
                //use these tags to check the files present on submission
                foreach($tags as $tag){
                    if(array_key_exists($tag,$_FILES)){
                        if(!empty($_FILES) && $_FILES[$tag]["name"] != "" && isset($_FILES[$tag]["name"])){
                            $config = array (
                                'source_image' => $_FILES[$tag]["name"],
                                'image_library' => 'gd',
                                'upload_path' => $path, 
                                'file_name' =>  $id . '_' . $tag . '.jpg',
                                'allowed_types' => 'png|jpg|jpeg',
                                'overwrite' => TRUE,
                                'max_size' => '2000',   
                            );
                            $this->_CI->upload->initialize($config);
                            if(!$this->_CI->upload->do_upload()){
                                echo 'Error creating image. ';
                                echo $this->_CI->upload->display_errors();
                            }else{
                                echo 'Success saving to temp folder';
                            }

                            //kapag failed
                            if(!$this->_CI->upload->do_upload()){
                                echo 'Error creating image.';
                                echo $this->_CI->upload->display_errors();
                            }else{
                                //now, the $path will become our resource path for copying and creating thumbnails.
                                $resouce_path = $config['upload_path'] . '/' . $config['file_name'];
                                $this->img_create_thumb($resouce_path, $folder);
                            }

                        }else{
                            //Hindi na dapat marating to!
                            echo $tag . ' not present ';
                        }
                    }else{
                        //use default pictures
                        echo $tag . ' not present ';
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

However it gives me the following error:

> Error creating image.
>
> You did not select a file to upload.
>
> Error
>   creating image.
>
> You did not select a file to upload.
>
> You did
>   not select a file to upload.
>
> Error creating image.
>
> You did not
>   select a file to upload.
>
> Error creating image.
>
> You did not select
>   a file to upload.
>
> You did not select a file to upload.
>
> right
>   not present left not present

I think I did not correctly specified which resource on the $_FILES should be uploaded.

Your response would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by supplying the indices in codeigniter's do_upload()

```
$this->_CI->upload->do_upload($tag);
```

Comment: You asked a question to answer it yourself?If you look at the CI doc or search for your problem you would find lots of answer.